# CODED UI TESTS: is there a way to add a warning in html report?

Tags: warnings, coded-ui-tests, assertion

In my Coded UI Test project, I need to check if few Labels or Messages are consistent with the context. But those checks are not critical if not consistent and I need to output them only as warnings.

Note that I'm using nested ordered tests to use only one global ordered test with vstest.console.exe and get in one shot the overall test coverage report.

Till now I was creating assertions to check those consistencies, but an assertion failure leads to Test failure, then to ordered test failure and then to playback stop.

I tried to change Playback.PlaybackSettings.ContinueOnError value before and after the assertion: this works as I expect as the assertion is well reported as a warning in the html report file. But whatever, it causes the ordered test to stop and then my global ordered test chaining to fail...

I tried to use TestContext.WriteLine too instead of creating assert, but it seems that this is not output in the html report.

So my question is:
is there any way to create an assertion only as a Warning that will be output in the html report file and that doesn't lead to a test failure?

Thanks a lot for any answer and help on this ;)

Comment: No one for any clue for this or any workaround?
If my question is not clear enough or not 
legitimate enough, don't hesitate to tell me or explain it to me ;)

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got my solution with developping my own Warning Engine to integrate Warnings in test report, 'cause I found no existing solution for that with the current Coded UI Test Assertion engine.

I'll try to take some time to post generic parts of the code structure with comments translated in english (we're french so default comments are french for now...), but here are the main step lines :

1. Create a template based on the UITestActionLog.html original file
   report structure of Coded UI Test engine, with only the start 
   bloc and the javascript functions and CSS declarations in it.
2. Create an assertion class with a main function to manage insertion
   of Warning html bloc in the html report first created from the template.
3. Then create custom assert functions to call the main function
   whereever on runtime, and custom Stopwatch to inject elapsed time in
   the report ('cause I could'nt found a way to get back the elapsed
   time directly from the Coded UI Test engine).

That's it.
Just a proposition as a way to do it, maybe not the best one but it worked for me. I'll try to take time to put blocl codes to be clearer on it.